# What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, outerxml

When I build XML up from scratch with `XmlDocument`, the `OuterXml` property already has everything nicely indented with line breaks.  However, if I call `LoadXml` on some very "compressed" XML (no line breaks or indention) then the output of `OuterXml` stays that way.  So ...

What is the simplest way to get beautified XML output from an instance of `XmlDocument`?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Based on the other answers, I looked into [`XmlTextWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter) and came up with the following helper method:

```
static public string Beautify(this XmlDocument doc)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "  ",
        NewLineChars = "\r\n",
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
    };
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It's a bit more code than I hoped for, but it works just peachy.

Comment: You might even consider creating your utility method as an extension method to the XmlDocument class.

Comment: Oddly enough, for me this does nothing except setting the xml header's encoding to UTF-16. Strangely enough, it does this even if I explicitly set `settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: The encoding problem can be solved by using a `MemoryStream` + `StreamWriter` with a specified encoding instead of the `StringBuilder`, and getting the text with `enc.GetString(memstream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memstream.Length);`. The end result is still in no way formatted, though. Could it be related that I'm starting from a read document which already has formatting? I just want my new nodes to be formatted as well.

Comment: I'm tempted to modify the `"\r\n"`to `Environment.Newline`.

Comment: You don't need the setting options about new line. The ones about indentation seem to be enough. Two spaces are also the default, so you'd simply need `Indent = true`. I prefer tabs though so I also need `IndentChars = "\t"`. (Tabs save space, too.)

Comment: `doc.PreserveWhitespace` should not be set to true. Otherwise it fails if it contains already partial indentation.

Comment: @Pharap That makes the code environment-dependent; `Environment.Newline` does not always equal `"\r\n"`. Files you export often have fixed, system-independent specs in terms of their line endings.

Comment: @Nyerguds As it happens, [`Environment.NewLine` would be the default anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinechars?view=net-8.0#definition). If a specific line ending _were_ needed then it would likely be better to have a parameter for that. When not provided as a parameter, using a platform-specific value seems a reasonable default behaviour, whereas simply preferring `"\r\n"` seems a bit Windows-centric. In my experience the platform specific value would be desirable, but different people may use this code for different purposes.

Answer (score 52):

As adapted from [Erika Ehrli's](http://blogs.msdn.com/erikaehrli/archive/2005/11/16/IndentXMLFilesandDocuments.aspx) blog, this should do it:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");
// Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml", null)) {
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

Comment: the closing of the `using` statement will automatically close the writer when `Dispose()` is called.

Comment: For me, this only indents one line. I still have dozens of other lines that are not indented.

Answer (score 44):

Or even easier if you have access to Linq

```
try
{
    RequestPane.Text = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(RequestPane.Text).ToString();
}
catch (System.Xml.XmlException xex)
{
            displayException("Problem with formating text in Request Pane: ", xex);
}
```

Comment: very nice! *thumbs up* advantage over accepted answer is that it won't produce an XML comment so works better for an XML fragment

Comment: Oddly, this removes the `<?xml ...?>` and the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` from the XML.  OK for a fragment, but not desirable for a full document.

Comment: This is the only way which worked for me. All of the other methods using xmltextwriter, Formatting = Formatting.Indented and XmlWriterSettings does NOT reformat the text, but this method does.

Answer (score 22):

A shorter extension method version

```
public static string ToIndentedString( this XmlDocument doc )
{
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
    var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter) {Formatting = Formatting.Indented};
    doc.Save( xmlTextWriter );
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This works very well and doesn't involve creating unnecessary files to disk

Answer (score 14):

If the above Beautify method is being called for an `XmlDocument` that already contains an `XmlProcessingInstruction` child node the following exception is thrown:

> Cannot write XML declaration.
>   WriteStartDocument method has already
>   written it.

This is my modified version of the original one to get rid of the exception:

```
private static string beautify(
    XmlDocument doc)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var settings =
        new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                IndentChars = @"    ",
                NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
                NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
            };

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
    {
        if (doc.ChildNodes[0] is XmlProcessingInstruction)
        {
            doc.RemoveChild(doc.ChildNodes[0]);
        }

        doc.Save(writer);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

It works for me now, probably you would need to scan all child nodes for the `XmlProcessingInstruction` node, not just the first one?

---

**Update April 2015:**

Since I had another case where the encoding was wrong, I searched for how to enforce UTF-8 without BOM. I found [this blog post](http://www.timvw.be/2007/01/08/generating-utf-8-with-systemxmlxmlwriter/) and created a function based on it:

```
private static string beautify(string xml)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "\t",
        NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
        Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)
    };

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
    {
        doc.Save(writer);
        var xmlString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        return xmlString;
    }
}
```

Comment: it will not work if you put cdata section inside parent node and before child node

Comment: MemoryStream doesn't seem to be needed, at least on my side. In settings I set : `Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` and `OmitXmlDeclaration = true`

Answer (score 7):

```
XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(writer);
xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    public static string FormatXml(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            return doc.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return xml;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer below could definitely do with some explanation however it worked for me and is much simpler than the other solutions.

Comment: It seems you need to import the system.link.XML assembly for this to work on PS 3.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use:

```
writer.WriteRaw(space_char);
```

Like this sample code, this code is what I used to create a tree view like structure using XMLWriter :

```
private void generateXML(string filename)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                //new line
                writer.WriteRaw("\n");
                writer.WriteStartElement("treeitems");
                //new line
                writer.WriteRaw("\n");
                foreach (RootItem root in roots)
                {
                    //indent
                    writer.WriteRaw("\t");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("treeitem");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", root.name);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("uri", root.uri);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("fontsize", root.fontsize);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("icon", root.icon);
                    if (root.children.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (ChildItem child in children)
                        {
                            //indent
                            writer.WriteRaw("\t");
                            writer.WriteStartElement("treeitem");
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("name", child.name);
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("uri", child.uri);
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("fontsize", child.fontsize);
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("icon", child.icon);
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                            //new line
                            writer.WriteRaw("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    //new line
                    writer.WriteRaw("\n");
                }

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

            }

        }
```

This way you can add tab or line breaks in the way you are normally used to, i.e. \t or \n

Answer (score 2):

When implementing the suggestions posted here, I had trouble with the text encoding. It seems the encoding of the `XmlWriterSettings` is ignored, and always overridden by the encoding of the stream. When using a `StringBuilder`, this is always the text encoding used internally in C#, namely UTF-16.

So here's a version which supports other encodings as well.

IMPORTANT NOTE: The formatting is completely ignored if your `XMLDocument` object has its `preserveWhitespace` property enabled when loading the document. This had me stumped for a while, so make sure not to enable that.

My final code:

```
public static void SaveFormattedXml(XmlDocument doc, String outputPath, Encoding encoding)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";
    settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace;

    using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(memstream, encoding))
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sr, settings))
    using (FileStream fileWriter = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        if (doc.ChildNodes.Count > 0 && doc.ChildNodes[0] is XmlProcessingInstruction)
            doc.RemoveChild(doc.ChildNodes[0]);
        // save xml to XmlWriter made on encoding-specified text writer
        doc.Save(writer);
        // Flush the streams (not sure if this is really needed for pure mem operations)
        writer.Flush();
        // Write the underlying stream of the XmlWriter to file.
        fileWriter.Write(memstream.GetBuffer(), 0, (Int32)memstream.Length);
    }
}
```

This will save the formatted xml to disk, with the given text encoding.

Comment: The fact that preserveWhitespace breaks the formatting functionality of XmlWriter is a crucial piece of information - this was tripping me up for quite a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string of XML, rather than a doc ready for use, you can do it this way:

```
var xmlString = "<xml>...</xml>"; // Your original XML string that needs indenting.
xmlString = this.PrettifyXml(xmlString);

private string PrettifyXml(string xmlString)
{
    var prettyXmlString = new StringBuilder();

    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);

    var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = " ",
        NewLineChars = "\r\n",
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
    };

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(prettyXmlString, xmlSettings))
    {
        xmlDoc.Save(writer);
    }

    return prettyXmlString.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more simplified approach based on the accepted answer:

```
static public string Beautify(this XmlDocument doc) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true
    };

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }

    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

Setting the new line is not necessary. Indent characters also has the default two spaces so I preferred not to set it as well.

Answer (score -1):

Set **PreserveWhitespace** to **true** before **Load**.

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
document.Load(filename);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my own anwser here, this is wrong; enabling `PreserveWhitespace` on load makes it _ignore_ formatting options for the output. It'll preserve what is _already there_, but it will prevent you from reformatting the output how you want it.