# JSON.NET XML to String

Tags: c#, xml, string, json, json.net

```
        string json = "{"Animal":{"id":"123","verified":true}}"

        XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);

        returnXml = doc.ToString();
```

Why does "ReturnXml" return the following text "System.Xml.XmlDocument" and not the XML output in string format?

---

http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print XML, you need to use `InnerXml`

```
doc.InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString` method of XmlDocument is not set to output a pretty version of the xml contained therein.

You're best bet may be to just convert that XmlDocument to an XDocument, since that supports a ToString method that outputs actual XML:

```
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
XDocument linqXML = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc)); 
returnXML = linqXML.ToString();
```

Comment: how do I fix it so it outputs xml string?

Comment: You'll have to do it yourself.  check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument