# Visual Studio-like code formatting in Scintilla control

Tags: formatting, scintilla

Is it possible to format XML code in scintilla in the same way that Visual Studio does when you paste some xml into a xml file.

At the moment, the xml that I retrieve is on one line and therefore hard to work with, it would be great if the xml could be formatted properly on load.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use NotePad++ or http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/

Comment: This is not answering my question, I'm looking for a solution for a Windows Form control called Scintilla, see below the solution

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about SciTE, as a one time thing. Let me look around I apologize for the mistake. I didn't understand the context. You want to include this functionality in an application you are making.

Comment: Could you use something like the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string and then load the result into your Scintilla form control?

Comment: Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument/203581#203581

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to get .NET to do interpret the XML and export it as a formatted string, using XMLTextWriter - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string). This assumes you're using Scintilla inside .NET though - you'd have to use the XML features of your platform of choice if not.