# Convert string to presentable XML format in SSIS

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, ssis, pretty-print

I have the following string that I want to convert to a presentable XML format. Presentable meaning, properly indented and carriage returned at appropriate spots. For some reason, I cant seem to get this to work.

```
<HTML><SSISLog><PackageProperty><PackageName>Package</PackageName><PackageID>{67D67690-D437-42DB-80A2-A7FB68353E70}</PackageID></PackageProperty></SSISLog></HTML>'
```

Can I use the xml task to do this job? Any inbuilt stored procedures for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the XML task will not beautify the XML. Add a script task and use the method that was provided on this answer [What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument)

And in case you aren't sure how to make the string into an xmldoc, this answer should show the way [Format XML String to Print Friendly XML String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123718/format-xml-string-to-print-friendly-xml-string)

Comment: I had patch the script on the link in a script task. I did that after a few small changes and it works fine. Thanks for the solution.