# Windows Form project proper format for XML in TextBox field

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

on my project i have a form in which i have `TextBox` in some point of executing my program i want to put `XML` string in my `TextBox` - nothing complicated.
 Problem lies in the format in which this `XML` is being displayed in `TextBox` which is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?><IOTPMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Element1>value</Element1><Element2>value</Element2><Element3>value</Element3></IOTPMessage>
```

I want it to look like proper `XML` look like (with new lines, tabulators) which is easy to read :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<IOTPMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Element1>value</Element1>
      <Element2>value</Element2>
      <Element3>value</Element3>
</IOTPMessage>
```

The way i put `XML` string to textBox:

```
TextBox someBox;
someBox.Append(XMLstring);
```

To be honest i don't even knew where to start - besides looking for proper articles or samples which i didn't find, maybe anyone of you can redirect me to somewhere where i can find solution?

Comment: How are you loading the xml string?

Comment: I am serializing the Object to XML using method `GetXMLFromObject(Object);` which return XMLstring

Comment: Here is an example on how to "beautify" XML documents in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument Maybe this helps?

Comment: Lennart, thank you it looks good, but i will be able to test it as soon as I install VisualStudio on my mobile computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `XmlTextWriter` in order to show proper `XML` Message like here:

```
MemoryStream w = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(w, Encoding.Unicode);

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xmlString);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
document.WriteContentTo(writer);

writer.Flush();
w.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(w);
return reader.ReadToEnd();
```