# how to get dataset in delphi that generate in asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, delphi, delphi-7

i wrote a `webservice` in asp.net that have select function that it's parameter is a string , return a `dataset` like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet Select(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("fname");
    dt.Columns.Add("lname");
    dt.Rows.Add("mehdi", "nine");
    dt.Rows.Add("ali", "javan");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    return ds;
}
```

when i see it's xml input it is like this:

```
<s:element name="Select">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="query" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="SelectResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SelectResult">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element ref="s:schema"/>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

in xml file we can see it's output is `SelectResult`. how can i convert it to datasource in `delphi7`?
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DaTaSet is not good As webservice return type for clients not using .net. You can try to retun XML here..

```
[WebMethod]
public string Select(string query)
{
    // your code
    return ds.GetXml();
}
```

This will give you XMl Like below

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <fname>mehdi</fname>
    <lname>nine</lname>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <fname>ali</fname>
    <lname>javan</lname>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Hope that you can process this to use as DataSource.

If you need indented XML check this answer [What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument/203581#203581)