# Display deserialized XML on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

How can I display XML output on ASP.NET page with XML tags?

```c#
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonOutput, "root");
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

I would like to get results on my page like this:

```xml
<root>
    <id>108013515952807</id>
    <posts>
        <data>
            <message>This...Game... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8Xsex0pqXY</message>
            <id>108013515952807_470604423027046</id>
            <created_time>2013-05-15T20:02:31+0000</created_time>
        </data>
        <data>
            <message>Streaming in a few minutes! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYnHDT6V82k</message>
            <id>108013515952807_470538076367014</id>
            <created_time>2013-05-15T16:46:36+0000</created_time>
        </data>
    </posts>
</root>
```

I tried this but I get no XML tags like in example above.

```c#
Response.Write("<BR>" + doc.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just put XML onto a webpage, the browser thinks it might be HTML and "renders" it, which is why you can't see the tags. You need to encode the XML

You can use the method

> Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(doc.OuterXml));

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
XElement.Parse(request.OuterXml).ToString()
```

If you want prettified XML string,

refer to: [What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument)

Comment: Do you want to return an prettified xml string? or just an application/xml content?

Comment: I would like to return a xml like in example above, which results I get with Console.WriteLine()