# How to format some XML and turn it into a string array holding the individual lines

Tags: c#, .net, xml, formatting

Whats the best way to turn some Xml into a well indented/formatted Xml and access the individual lines of the resulting Xml afterwards? I guess the first part of the problem (indenting/formatting) can be solved using an XmlTextWriter or something similar. But how do I get an array of lines out of the result? Do I have to split the string again? Are there more elegant options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to explain *why* you want to do that because it sounds like a complex solution to a non-problem

Comment: I need to prefix each line in the xml document with a customized linenumber.

Comment: Ah... Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to pretty print XML?**

```
string FormatXml(String Xml)
{
     try
     {
         XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Xml);
         return doc.ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         return Xml;
     }
 }
```

Alternative is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/203581/1163786

**How to build an array with lines from the XML?**

```
string[] lines = xml.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**Are there more elegant options?**

That depends on what "elegant" means to you.
If you find regular expressions elegant and powerful, then the solution above is amongst the elegant solutions. If you prefer non-regexp solutions, then utilizing the StringReader might be worth looking into:

```
using (System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml)) {
    string[] lines = = reader.ReadLine();
}
```