# Show XML content in div innertext

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml

I have my XML as a string and need to display it in a div 
I have searched all the ways to format an XML, but it doesn't work as I am finally binding my contents to a div.

Following is what I am using in my asp.net applicaion c# code.

```
request = //my xml string     
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(request);
divLogResults.InnerText = doc.ToString()
```

I have tried all the ways listed here as well

[What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument)

So this isn't a duplicate. How can I do this in a simple way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your XML content in a text area. I think this should work.

Web form:

```
   <textarea rows="20" cols="40" style="border:none;" runat="server" id="txtXML" readonly="true">
    </textarea>
```

Code behind:

```
request = // xml string     
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(request);
txtXML.Text = doc.ToString()
```

Please make sure your xml content has the header appended 
e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```