# XmlWriter writing everything to a single line

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I am writing an XML file, however when I go to read it it is all on the same line.

Can someone please look at my code and let know why its all appearing on the same line rather than in the correct format.

The code as you should see is writing a few nodes, then it is writing the code, name, formula, and so on...  It's also checking that the formula from datarow 8 and beyond are not duplicates

```
var exportFile = "c:\\temp\\export.xml";
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(exportFile);

xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("designExport");
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("designs");
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("design");
foreach (DataRow dr in xltbl.Rows)
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("code");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(dr[0].ToString());
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("name");
    xmlWriter.WriteString(dr[1].ToString());
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    for (var i = 2; i < xltbl.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i >= 8 && dr[i] != dr[i - 8])
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[i].ToString())) continue;
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("forumula");
            xmlWriter.WriteString(dr[i].ToString());
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("coverage");
            xmlWriter.WriteString("0");
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("usageFactor");
            xmlWriter.WriteString("0");
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
xmlWriter.Close();
```

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of the [`XmlWriter.Create(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcsse48t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method says that:

> An `XmlWriterSettings` object with default settings is used to create
> the writer. If you wish to specify the features to support on the
> created writer, use the overload that takes an `XmlWriterSettings`
> object as one of its arguments, and pass in a `XmlWriterSettings` object
> with the correct settings.

Apparently, the default settings is not what you want.

You must define the desired writer behaviour using the [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
// other settings...

XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(exportFile, settings);
```

There are quite a lot of properties you can define to adjust the generated output. Have a quick look at the documentation.

Comment: thank you, this has worked on the first few elements but the rest of the lines are still the same

Comment: think im sorted... was bad placements of `xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();`