# Formatting XML File into a form using LINQ c# Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, visual-studio

Need to some help here.  Trying to input an XML into a form in Visual Studio and have it display with the XML formatting in tact.  I have gotten it to display as one long line but need the formatting to be there.  I am using a label in the form to show the text, not sure if that is the best way or not but only way I could get it to work

This is in the Form1.cs

```
string FormatXML(string xml)
{
  XDocument.Load("Employee Roster.xml");
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  return(this.label1.Text = doc.ToString());
}
```

I have also tried

```
string FormatXML(string xml)
{
 XDocument.Load("Employee Roster.xml");

 try
 {
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
   return(this.label1.Text = doc.ToString());
 }
 Catch
 {
   return xml
 }
```

I know there are other threads on this but they dont seem to specify how to define what file you are asking the form to read(I.E. the Load method)

Comment: This answer looks like it may be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument

Comment: You probably want to put it in a text box not a label.

Comment: You don't want to have this label in there at all! What does a label have to do with parsing XML? `doc.ToString()` returns formatted XML.