# Indenting XML, but leaving everything else untouched

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My first question here, so bear with me. Basically, my problem is this:
Im building an XML IDE for an internal language. A feature of it should be to auto-indent the XML by using some command. Similar to what is found in Visual Studio etc.

Basically what I need is to turn the following Xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
        <to>Tove</to>

    <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>
```

Into:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>

    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>
```

That is indent - but touch nothing else. Is this possible in C# without writing an algorithm from scratch, i.e., with LINQ XDocument or some XmlWriter implementaion?

I've tried the following so far (from [What is the simplest way to get indented XML with line breaks from XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203528/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-indented-xml-with-line-breaks-from-xmldocument))

```cs
static public string Beautify(this XmlDocument doc)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "  ",
        NewLineChars = "\r\n",
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
    };
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
        doc.Save(writer);
    }
    return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

But this removes linebreaks and gives me:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with comments or answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try replacing all newlines with a custom tag (e.g. `<newline></newline>`, running the result through your existing Beautify code and then replacing the newline tags with proper newlines again.

UPDATE: Thinking about this more you might need to replace `\n\n` with '\n', but you get the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it would be really hard to handle not placing <newline></newline> inside tags and thus producing invalid xml.

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer since the suggestion ultimately lead me to a solution. The solution resembles the one given by Larry Smithmier in another answer, and involves 2+ passes over the xml.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Mark's good suggestion, this will beautify the XML string (but the code isn't very pretty):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>

<from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>";
        string output = Test.BeautifyXML(test);
        Console.Write(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
static class Test { 
    static public string BeautifyXML(this string docString)
    {
        docString = Regex.Replace(docString.Replace("\r", "<r></r>").Replace("\n", "<n></n>"),@"\?>(<r></r><n></n>)*", "?>");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(docString);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "  ",
            NewLineChars = "\r\n",
            NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
        };
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
        return Regex.Replace(sb.ToString().Replace("\r\n", ""), @"<r></r>( )*<n></n>", "\r\n").Replace("?>", "?>\r\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>

  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

instead of

```
NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
```

use

```
NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
```

The `None` setting tells the `XmlWriter` to leave the input unchanged. This setting is used when you not want any new-line processing.

Comment: Making that change doesn't impact the output.