# How to write a space between each element for a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, writer

I'm trying to add a space between each element in a XML file but I have no idea how to do it
This is what I have

```
if (sfdSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Data data = new Data();

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sfdSave.FileName))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("MyConnection");  

                writer.WriteElementString("Host", data.Host);                               
                writer.WriteElementString("User", data.User);                    
                writer.WriteElementString("Password", data.Password);                   
                writer.WriteElementString("Port", Convert.ToString(data.Port));                   

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

and this is what I did

```
        if (sfdSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Data data = new Data();

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sfdSave.FileName))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("MyConnection");  

                writer.WriteElementString("Host", data.Host);
                writer.WriteElementString("","\n");                               
                writer.WriteElementString("User", data.User);
                writer.WriteElementString("","\n");                    
                writer.WriteElementString("Password", data.Password);
                writer.WriteElementString("","\n");                   
                writer.WriteElementString("Port", Convert.ToString(data.Port));
                writer.WriteElementString("","\n");                   

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

That solution is not working

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: XmlWriter will not allow you to add spaces on the output's format, it's written to create well formated XML

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><MyConnection><Host>192.168.10.1</Host><User>ImTestingXML</User><Password>MyPassword</Password><Port>25</Port></MyConnection>

Comment: I want a blank space for each label

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought you meant a blank line XD, ok, try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: did u try adding  &#160; .. I think that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

how about if you try adding  `&#160;`

that might work..

-- Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have another method that "beautifies"  your xml string.

Found this in a similar post maybe it can help.

[Adding a helper to XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203581/5551854)

Answer (score 0):

try to use XmlSerializer so you need first to create class contains the all properties that you need and then use xmlSerializer.serialize in this case it will create an xml file in good layout

first create class named MyConnection

```
[Serializable]
public class MyConnection
{
public string User {get;set;}
public string password {get;set;}
public string port {get;set;}
public string host{get;set;}
}
```

then when you want to write this file

```
MyConnection con = new MyConnection {user ="" , password =""};
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(MyConnection));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Create)
{
serializer.serialize (stream ,con);
}
```

you can add attribute by adding above each property

```
[XmlAttribute]
```